# How to SELECT multiple records from MySQL DB in an Node.js based application & node-mysql driver?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am running the below query in mysql db and i want to store the results in an array ? How can I do that in node.js ?

```
SELECT ProductName FROM products;
```

Comment: Did you consult any tutorial yet?

Comment: yes, most examples are in php. i am looking for in node js

Comment: Node.js function `connection.query('query', results, fields)`   here results param is already a Array in JSON notation.

Comment: Yes, Thats what i noticed in the blog too - https://www.w3resource.com/node.js/nodejs-mysql.php. It returns the result in an array.

Comment: Guys who gave this new member so many negative votes, shall consider to teach new members, giving them a fair chance to learn about our community. 
I remember something like this happened to me my 1st question, which put me of the StackOverflow for years.
Let's keep our community of Stackers, happy and welcoming Stackers, rather than Screwers!
As for @James, please pay attention to the changes of keywords I have made in the title and the description. Learning to search for existing solutions, using different keyphrases is as vital as ability to create beautiful and practical questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last SELECT statement you have described is almost correct except that it uses structure for the INSERT statement.

Here is **2 correct ways** to create and execute SELECT statements, the safe way, to avoid MySQL injections and to secure your database from possible attacks.

***1. Multiple Records***

```
    /**
     * Example of Selecting multiple rows form one MySQL table
     */

    var query = connection.query('SELECT ProductName FROM products', 
    [product_id], function(err, results) { 

         if (error) throw error; output error(s)

         // results[0]['ProductName'];
         // results[1]['ProductName'];
         // ...

    });
```

1. Using a prepared Statement targeting for specific rows:

   ```
    /**
    * Example of Selecting one record using MySQL Table ID
    */

   var category_id = 5; 
   var query = connection.query('SELECT ProductName FROM products WHERE CategoryId=?', 
   [category_id], function(err, results) {

        if (error) throw error; output error(s)

        // results[0]['ProductName'];
        // results[1]['ProductName'];
        // ...

   });
   ```
2. Using mysql.escapeId() method

   ```
   var category_id = x; 
   var sql    = 'SELECT productName FROM products WHERE category_id = ' + connection.escape(category_id);
   connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {

        if (error) throw error; output error(s)

        // results[0]['ProductName'];
        // results[1]['ProductName'];
        // ...

   });
   ```